# If I am a particular race (black) for example, in Jannah can I become any race I way yo be?

Tags: halal-haram, jannah

What if I don't want to be a particular race, or nationality of ethnicity in this Dunya. Can I wish or ask Allah to change my race, color, or ethnicity. Basically can I be white in the next life if I am black in this dunya? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

In Jannah we won't have race differences.
The only difference will be the amount of good we did in this world
So the more good we did in this world, the higher status we get in the next life

We will be resurrected in a different type of body than the body of this dunya.
So presumably there will be no color differences since man is created equal?

Comment: "there will be no color differences " .. can you share a reference please